# Minecraft MinecartChest team selector not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm using vanilla version 1.10.2. I have added a MinecartChest to a team using this command: `/scoreboard teams join orange @e[type=MinecartChest,r=3]`. I can tell that it has been added to the team, because the name of the chest changes color to orange, plus it is listed when I run `/scoreboard teams list orange`.

I then try to run `/say @e[team=orange]` but the minecart's name isn't listed. In addition, trying to use the selector `@e[type=MinecartChest,team=orange]` in any other command fails as well. However, if I run `\say @e[type=MinecartChest]`, the minecart chest is listed normally.

Is this an issue that has been encountered before, or is this behavior normal? Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Skylinerw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/273668/112980) said, the `team` selector parameter doesn't work on non-living entities (except Armor Stands). A way to work around this is to add a tag to the entity. For example, if you add something to the `orange` team, also add an `orange` tag to it:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=MinecartChest,r=3] add orange
```

Then you can select it like normal, but using a `tag` parameter instead of a `team` parameter:

```
/say @e[tag=orange] Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

The `team` parameter will throw out any targets that are not "living" (keeping only players, all mobs, and armor stands). While a non-living entity may be inserted into a team, you may not target them with a selector based on their team.